# How to use a combination of translate and ng-bind-html to generate a ui-sref link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm a bit stumped on how to generate a working `ui-sref` link from a translated string.

I'm using angular 1.4.9
with angular translate 2.9.0

Here's is the relevant code

```
<div ng-bind-html="$scope.getTranslatedText(someObject)"></div>

controller {
   function(value) {
       this.$translate.isPostCompilingEnabled(); // Returns true
       return this.$translate.instant("taskNames."+value.parameters['messageId'], value.parameters);
   }
}

My translation has the following string.

taskInstructions{
    someMessageId: "Here is some text <a ui-sref=\"goSomewhere\">Some more text</a>"
}
```

My translation returns the text as expected, and if I don't have the `ng-bind-html` the ui-sref is there, but once I add in the `ng-bind-html` the ui-sref go away. I've tried compile, but that didn't appear to work, although I'm not sure if I was using that correctly.

I tried `$sce.trustAsHtml` on the output of the translation and that got the `ui-sref` to show up in the html output, but it didn't actually link anywhere. I feel like I'm missing some steps somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out what angular wants me to do to get the ui-sref to function.

Any ideas on what the best practices are to get this to work?

Comment: why do you need `ng-bind-html` for this in the first place? It is generally only used for displaying user submitted content and doesn't compile directives

Comment: Not sure if I need the `ng-bind-html`, was using initially when I was trying to get the link working, might just be a red herring now, but I'm not sure what the correct steps are to get this working. If I just try the translate, I just get text back, so no functioning html.

Comment: If you want to output a dynamic anchor tag, then yes you have to use `ng-bind-html` but you must tell angular that it is ok to use by first using `$sce.trustAsHtml()` Also `ng-bind-html="getTranslatedText(someObject)"`, you don't need `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Not using translate, but maybe this helps. We use `$sce` and `$state`:

**HTML**

```
<section class="adb-layout-row" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
  <div class="adb-layout-default">
    <h5><a ng-click="vm.open(post)">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
    <div ng-bind-html="post.html"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
$q.when(getPosts()).then(function(data) {
  vm.posts =  data.posts.map(function(post){
      return {
        title: post.title,
        html: $sce.trustAsHtml(post.description),
        url: post.url
      };
    });
});

angular.extend(vm, {
  open: function(post) {
    $state.go(post.url);
  }
});
```